# How do I make certain -webkit-transitions refer to :focus and some to :hover?

Tags: javascript, animation, css

In my code, I want my `-webkit-transition: border 2s;` to refer on hover, and for `-webkit-transition: border 2s; // a different colored border on :focus` to refer on focus. How do I do that? Does it require JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
selector {
   border: 1px red solid;
   -webkit-transition: border 2s;
}
selector:hover { border: 5px red solid; }
selector:focus { border: 1px green solid; }
```

in the selector you specify a `border` shorthand property and a transition that will change only that specific property

so, on `hover` and `focus` pseudoclasses you will change that specific property based on what you want to change

Answer (score 0):

```
*selector:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 2s; }

*selector:focus {
    -webkit-transition: border 2s; }
```

Pretty basic CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite a novice in CSS3. Edit: I upvoted, not downvoted.

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work. See what happens, it's like a 5px black border; I don't want that -- http://jsbin.com/ifilag/3/edit

Comment: It works.... (http://jsbin.com/ifilag/6/edit) you weren't seeing a change because you've got both borders set the same essentially. The eye can't really tell the difference between a 1 pixel black border and a 1 pixel dark blue border.